# Using IF on a list of outcomes and changing the value of the outcome

Tags: arrays, if-statement, google-sheets, vlookup, google-query-language

I'm trying to use the IF function to create a formula that answers TRUE based on multiple outcomes - I've definitely taken the wrong turn in the code I created:

```
=IF(E3="S2"OR"S3"OR"S4"OR"S5"OR"S6"OR"S7"OR"S8"OR"S9"OR"S10"OR"S11"OR"S12"OR"S13"OR"S14"OR"S15"OR"S16"OR"S17")
```

I also want the box to read 90 - e.g. IF the answer is from the above range, the response in the box is 90 rather than true/false.

Lastly, I want to automate this down the column so that any new rows added automatically include the formula.

Additional info - this is how I've put in the suggested code - you can see it doesn't continue down the column as intended:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
=IF(REGEXMATCH(QUERY(S2:S17;;9^9); E3); 90; "no match")
```

but maybe you want this in row 2:

```
=INDEX(IF(S2:S=E3; 90; ))
```

---

### update:

```
=INDEX(IF(E2:E="",,IFNA(VLOOKUP(E2:E, S:U, 3, 0), 220)))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks player0 - This does the first two parts - is it possible to make it automatically do it for the rest of the E column without dragging down the list?

Comment: I've added an image below!

Comment: @MatthewHarrison can you share a copy of your sheet?

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1CIbDDk3IpmXqr5ky3cwViW24gCmohA4vdFMtOW9IYdY/edit?usp=sharing - ideally I want to add in that if the codes are not matched and given £90 then the value should be £220 if this is a possible extra thing to add! If not, just automatically adding the £90 value. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @MatthewHarrison see cell F2

Comment: Looks good and looks lie it works - thank you for the help! I'm playing around with it on the original now.

Comment: @MatthewHarrison answer updated